# Invalid_grant foursquare API access token

Tags: python, foursquare

I'm using foursquare API python client from mLewisLogic code from Github.
Honestly i don't understand about access token in foursquare API. It's only valid for 1 request?

Here's my code

```
import json

def setup():
client = foursquare.Foursquare(client_id='CLIENT_ID', client_secret='CLIENT_SECRET', redirect_uri='http://localhost')

auth_uri = client.oauth.auth_url()

code = "CODE" 
user_access_token = client.oauth.get_token(code)
client.set_access_token(user_access_token)
return client

if __name__ == '__main__':
     client = setup()
     file = open('dataHasil.json', 'wb')
     abc = json.dumps(client.users.search(params={'twitter': 'dindaasusanti'}))
     file.write(abc.encode())
```

Code above works, but if i add 2 more lines.

```
 abcd = json.dumps(client.users.search(params={'twitter': 'path'}))
 file.write(abcd.encode())
```

It produce error

```
Response format invalid , missing meta property. data: {'error':'invalid_grant'}
```

please help me, i want to search many user account's information

note : i paste the CODE manually following instruction from https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#access

Comment: problem solved, code is unique for each section, so it shouldn't hard coded.